# How can i let Python extract variables from a remote file when rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

so basically i want jinja2 to extract variables from a remote file instead of specifying these in the python file where jinja gets loaded when rendering.

example:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader*

ENV = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('./templates')) 
template = ENV.get_template("base.j2")
output = template.render(file)
```

with `file` referencing a file where variables are stored.

what would be your guess on the best way to do this.

i for example want to refer file to a remote python file where a dictionary is stored, but how does python extract the variables from that remote file.

i thought of the open and read() commands, i actually am able to read the remote file but what would be the best way to extract the vars from a remote dictionary (a remote file with a dictionary stored on to it)?

Comment: Well you want to render a HTML file with variables from another file? I don't think this is behavoiur that is already in jinja2. So you need to read your file, get out the vars and the pass it like normal to your tempalte you want to render. I could be wrong, but I think there is no easy way. Can I ask you why you want to read vars from a file? Why don't use a db to store data?

Comment: yes exactly how you suggested it but how can i do this the best way (extract the vars from the file once it gets opened and read), and no this is not ment for a HTML file. the purpose is to be used for network automation, file references to a unique file that is ment for a specific network device. i want these to be stored in a unique folder instead of throwing lots of dictionaries for all the networking devices in the same python file that processes them.

Comment: I don't know enough about the file. Is it a txt file? How are the variables described there? And can you answer why you don't use a db?

Comment: a db such as a SQL one would also be sufficient but this goes a bit further than my initial thought,  i wanted to start easy by referencing file to a python file where a dict is stored. 

easy said: i had not thought about a DB since this goes a bit further when it comes to research and gaining info how to do this with a DB. 

remote file has something like this:
r1 = {"hostname": "router1", "lo0ip": "101.1.1.1"}

what would be your opinion on best way to extract these if they are in a remote file.

Comment: In python readin out a txt file isn't that hard. Read this doc -> https://stackabuse.com/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/

Comment: Then use this doc to transform it to dictionaries -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

Comment: If anythin is not clear, let me know!

Comment: @Wimanicesir top , solved, thanks. the tip about the db is pretty good ill look into that aswell.

Comment: @Wimanicesir, Hello, i hope you are doing well, i have a simple question since i am starting to consider MongoDB as a way to store info just as my example above About networking devices. But would you mind telling me what kind of advantages a DB would have compared to my example of storing data in just a python file? Your reply Will be valued.